# CNN for a regression problem

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I have tons of matrices as inputs and their corresponding outputs, which are also matrices. In other words, my goal is to train a network that would predict me the matrix output based on the matrix input.

I believe that there's some dynamics between the matrix elements, thus I prefer CNN. But I don't really know how to approach this, as I can't come up with the output layer. How could I build a network that has both 16x16 matrices as input and output. I'm using keras on R.

Thanks!

Comment: If you can create 16x16 dimensional input layer, you should be able to create an output layer of the same dimensionality without any issues. Please [show what you have tried so far](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

Comment: I don't think it was fair to downvote. The question is clear and I have stated that the only part of my model that is missing is the architecture of layers. Everything else is taken care of. I just wanted some advice how to set up layers such that the inputs and outputs are both 16x16 matrices. This is easily done with regular NN, but not with CNN.

Comment: (I did not downvote, I just used the link.) Without knowing precisely what you already have, it is not possible to give you advice on how to add the output layer you want on top of the model. Please show us the code or a graphical representation of the layers you have so far. Then, we can suggest what to put on top.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? If yes, I would very much want to take a look of your architecture.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I never finished this project, but looking back at this I would not apply CNN. I think LSTM or RNN for an input where I concatenate the rows of the matrix into single sequence would be a fruitful option.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a type of UNet (https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597). This kind of architecture has downsampling layers, followed by up sampling layers to get back to the original spatial dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Problem is that I am not handling images, only numerical matrices. Thus, data augmentation isn't really helpful in this situation.

Comment: They key features of UNets is not their data augmentations, it's that the output shape of your predictions can be made the same as your input, which seemed to be the important part of your problem. Also images _are_ just numerical matrices.